# Disable drag/move of a graphic picture marker using arcgis javascript 4.x

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Using ArcGIS Javascript API 4.x.  I have the following picture marker:

```
// graphics layer
graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
theMap.add(graphicsLayer);

// point symbol
const pointSymbol = {
  type: "picture-marker",
  url: "pictures/mymarker.png",
  width: "32px",
  height: "32px"
};

// graphic object to hold picture marker
const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
  geometry: myPoint,
  symbol: pointSymbol
});
graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
```

My question is how do I disable selection of the marker and how do I disable drag of the marker?

I was hoping there is a setting such as **draggable: false** but this does not exist:

```
const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: myPoint,
      symbol: pointSymbol,
      draggable: false  // THIS DOES NOT EXIST
    });
```

**Solution**

Thanks to Cabesuon's example below, I figured out the issue why the point was becoming draggable.  By default actually the point should not be draggable.  But if you create a sketch object in the same graphicslayer, everything becomes draggable.  The solution was simple: just create the sketch object using a different name.  In the above example, I had:

```
sketch = new Sketch({
view: view,
layer: graphicsLayer,
...
```

I just changed it to:

```
sketch = new Sketch({
view: view,
layer: createDifferentLayerNameHereJustForSketch,
...
```

And the problem was resolved.  The point is no longer draggable.

Comment: How are you moving or dragging the graphics?.

Comment: Hi Cabesuon!  I am using the mouse to move the picture marker symbol graphic.

Comment: Sorry I was not that specific, are you using `Sketch` widget or `SketchViewModel`?

Comment: Hi Cabesuon.  I am not using Sketch or SketchViewModel.  The point is coming from the server and directly assigned in this line: geometry: myPoint

Comment: Can you share the piece of code used to move the graphic?

Comment: Hi Cabesuon.  The only code is above.  The rest is perfomed with the mouse.  Once you create the above pointGraphic, the map lets you drag the marker around the map (mymarker.png stated above) by selecting it with the left mouse button.  I dont want the marker to be draggable.  I want it to be in a fixed location. (Such as using draggable: false for the graphic object, but that setting does not exist)

Comment: Check the "answer" and lets continue in the comments, do not worry we will find a solution for your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the left mouse "drag" (click, hold and move) button action is to pan the view and the right mouse "drag" button action is to rotate the view. You should NOT be able to move a graphic or feature just with the code you add to the question.

This is a simple snippet to show what I am saying.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>
        Picture Marker Symbol
    </title>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/"></script>
    <script src="https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/satellites-3d/live/satellite.js"></script>

    <script>
        require([
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/views/MapView",
            "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
            "esri/Graphic",
            "esri/request"
        ], (Map, MapView, GraphicsLayer, Graphic, esriRequest) => {
            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "satellite"
            });

            const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
                zoom: 5,
                center: [-101.94981250000075, 41.20977753557709],
            });

            const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

            const graphic = new Graphic({
                geometry: {
                    type: "point", // autocasts as new Point()
                    x: -101.94981250000075,
                    y: 41.20977753557709
                },
                symbol: {
                    type: "picture-marker", // autocasts as new PictureMarkerSymbol()
                    url: "https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/satellites-3d/live/satellite.png",
                    width: 64,
                    height: 64
                }
            });

            graphicsLayer.add(graphic);

            map.add(graphicsLayer);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example Cabesuon!  Your example led me to the answer.  Even though I was not using a sketch object for the point, I was using the same GraphicsLayer later on to define a sketch object.  The solution was very simple: create the sketch object GraphicsLayer object with a different variable name!

Comment: Cabesuon, thank you for the solution!  By any chance would you know how to resolve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76112875