# Featurelayer going to server multiple times for same feature

Tags: arcgis-js-api

When creating the most simple layer using ArcGIS javascript api (4.26):

```
// Creating layer
var myLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://...",
    renderer: {
               type: "simple",
               symbol: {
                        type: "simple-fill",
                        color: "yellow",
                        style: "solid",
                        outline: {
                                  color: "red",
                                  width: 1
                                 }
               }
              }
});

// Adding it to the map
view.when(function () {
    view.map.add(myLayer);
});
```

I am only returning back one feature (objectid).  However, opening the network tab in chrome, reveals that it calls the server 3 times for same request.  All 3 times it returns the same response with the same objectid.  On the request the only parameter I noticed different on the 3 calls is the quantizationParameters sent as part of the request, specifically the xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax values were different on the 3 calls.

I would like to perform only one request to the server and eliminate the duplicate requests to the server.

My question is:

- How do I turn off "quantize" in arcgis 4.x?  (quantize: "false" from arcgis javascript 3.x does not work)
- What other option is there to only make one request to the server instead of three requests?

**Attempts to fix the issue**

I tried an old flag (quantize) from ArcGIS Javascript Api 3.x but it has no effect.  It still sends the quantizationParameters to the server:

```
// Creating layer
var myLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://...",
    quantize: "false",
...
```

Thank You

Comment: I am not sure about the quantize option you mention. But as far as I know `FeatureLayer` in the 4.x version only has one strategy for fetching the features, I am guessing that is on demand. In version 3.x you could set other options using `mode` option, like snapshot or select. I think is something that could be added in future versions. BTW, you want this for any purpose or limitation? it might be other options in some cases.

Comment: Hi Cabesuon thank you for your response.  Basically I would like to limit the GET request to only one call to the server instead of multiple calls doing the same thing.  When the FeatureLayer is created, it is making the same GET request 3 times to the server just to get one ObjectId.

Comment: I think that is probably because it is requesting in the initial animation to the initial extent, that is my guess. If you have a "reasonable" number of features, they do not get update or they not "often" updated it, what you could do is query all the features from the layer and then create the feature layer with local features. In that way you will have one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Cabesuon's suggestion, I was able to get this working.  I was not able to use a FeatureLayer, since using a FeatureLayer even when querying the objects locally would still hit the server when I displayed the FeatureLayer.  It is possible that with additional time and knowledge, FeatureLayer might work.  But my solution was to query the objects and then use a GraphicsLayer to display them.  This worked since there was only one hit to the server during the query.  Here is some of the code I used from this example:

[Query a feature layer sql](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/query-a-feature-layer-sql/)